# How can I fix problem with istream when I tried to put "kv" in class and out of it?

Tags: c++, windows

So I made this code and I get error that "kv is undefined" which is completely true, but I have no idea what to do now.
Link is here: https://hastebin.com/bowayuhuya.cpp

Well, not much. I tried without it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add your code directly to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, Kompleksni& c)
{
    cout << "Unesite realni dio ";
    in >> c.re;
    cout << "Unesite imaginarni dio ";
    in >> c.im;
    fillVector(c, kv);//this line is causing the error
    return in;
}
```

the error occurs in this function because kv is not declared in the scope of this function

Comment: Ye I know that's why I asked how to fix it.

Comment: You can try to make it a global variable

Comment: either make kv global so that it's always in scope, or pass it into the function